# Ajax Update panel doesnt work on Facebook SDK 5.0.3

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to do a Facebook app (using facebook-sdk-c#), when I add a Script manager and Update Panel for ajax, I clicked a button and receive an error:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed
```

What can I do ? is the problem related to Facebook or some events on it or my update panel

Answer (score 0):

first you are working within an iframe and there are the Facebook events the best way to avoid this error is to use j query it will help you a lot and for your question here are some useful links :

http://forums.asp.net/t/1037846.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/t/1392827.aspx

http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/137904-how-solve-Sys-WebForms-PageRequestManagerParserErrorException-error.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/9eaab93c-37c9-4343-889e-66ee29465d28

http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3159841/Sys-WebForms-PageRequestManagerParserErrorExceptio.aspx

if it helps mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

I found this site to list the reasons out well. http://mysoftskill.blogspot.com.au/2009/11/syswebformspagerequestmanagerparsererro.html

For me it was Server.Transfer I was using for performance reasons.